# Entity Framework method to query based on a complete object

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

How can I achieve following query method in Entity Framework,
 below is a snippet from NHibernate documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

```
 Example example = Example.create(cat)
    .excludeZeroes()           //exclude zero valued properties
    .excludeProperty("color")  //exclude the property named "color"
    .ignoreCase()              //perform case insensitive string comparisons
    .enableLike();             //use like for string comparisons
 List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add(example)
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is LINQ based. Linq is said to be a declarative language, which means so much as telling *what* to do in stead of *how* to do it (imperative). A statement like

```
context.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderDate).Distinct();
```

is a declarative shortcut, if you like, for a 'ceremonial' `foreach` statement in which `OrderDate`s are added to a list if they were not added to it before.

I'm not an expert in NHibernate or its criteria API, but the criteria API seems to be even more declarative than linq. That makes it hard to compare them. A few differences:

- The main one: query by example is not possible in EF.
- There is no way in linq to set behaviours for a whole query. For instance, if you want to exclude zero valued properties, you'll have to specify each one of them in a `where` predicate (which is closer to telling *how* to filter).
- Case sensitivity is downright underdeveloped in EF. For example, a statement like

  `People.Where(c => string.Compare( c.Name, "z", false) > 0)`

  will generate the same SQL as

  `People.Where(c => string.Compare( c.Name, "z", true) > 0)`

  The database collation determines the case sensitiveness of string comparisons.
- You can do `LIKE` queries, but, again, specified for each individual predicate:

  `People.Where (c => c.Name.Contains("a"))`

  (again: no differentiation in case)

So I can't really give a linq translation of your criteria query. I'd have to know the class properties to be able to specify all individual predicates.